# Wrap fetch function for token when using reactn

Tags: reactjs, jwt, reactn

I am using reactn to store the access and refresh tokens from logging in.  Normally, to do an API call, I would do something like the following...

```
fetch('/api/options/1/', {
    method: 'PUT',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify(state),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.access.token}`,
    },
})
```

But since the access token expires quickly, this can easily fail.  What I wanted to do is wrap the fetch function in a function like 'callAPI(url, options)' that would do the following:

1. Check if access token is expired (`global.auth.access.exp` variable).  If expired, first call `/api/auth/token/refresh` passing the refresh token to get a new access token
2. Send `fetch` with the `Authorization` header added automatically
3. Return response promise

What would be the best way to go about this when the auth information is stored in the `reactn` global state, so that in any component I could just import a function `callAPI` and do the API call?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using async/await syntax you can do it using below:

```
const fetchWrapper = async (URI, options) => {
    const auth = await fetch('/api/auth/token/refresh');
    const newOptions = {
        ...options,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.access.token}`,
        },
    }
    const res = await fetch(URI, newOptions);
    return res;
}
```

if you are not using async/await you can use below:

```
const fetchWrapper = (URI, options) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch('/api/auth/token/refresh').then((auth) => {
            const newOptions = {
                ...options,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.access.token}`,
                },
            }
            fetch(URI, newOptions).then(res => {
                resolve(res);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    })

    return promise;
}
```